# Mysql select sum(price) last month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables

```
stk
+---------+--------------+
| Field   | Type         |
+---------+--------------+
| id      | int(11)      | 
| name    | varchar(255) | 
| type_id | int(11)      |
+---------+--------------+

 stk_type

+-------+--------------+
| Field | Type         |
+-------+--------------+
| id    | int(11)      | 
| name  | varchar(255) | 
| price | int(11)      | 
+-------+--------------+

    customer
+-------+--------------+
| Field | Type         | 
+-------+--------------+
| id    | int(11)      | 
| fio   | varchar(255) | 
+-------+--------------+
and sales

+-------------+-----------+
| Field       | Type      | 
+-------------+-----------+
| id          | int(11)   | 
| customer_id | int(11)   |
| stk_id      | int(11)   | 
| date        | timestamp |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I need to select how much money i got for last month;
i don't know how to select it in one query.

```
SELECT stk_id FROM sales
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

So now i  have all the stk ids from last month, and i need to count sum, but how can i do it if i have duplicated keys: for example:

If last query returns `stk_id`'s *1,1,1,2 ,3,3*
how can i count the sum if price in `stk_type` equals next:

```
id 1 price 100
id 2 price 200
id 3 price 150
```

so for this example i should get this result 800;

I need to select all the stk_id and somehow to select price and count the sum.
Looking for help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sql query

```
SELECT stk_id, SUM(price) FROM sales
LEFT JOIN stk ON stk_id = stk.id
LEFT JOIN stk_type ON type_id  = stk_type.id
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
GROUP BY stk_id
```

Comment: its working, but i don;t need a `GROUP BY` without it, working perfeclty, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sales.stk_id, sum(stk_type.price) 
FROM sales LEFT JOIN stk_type ON (sales.stk_id=stk_type.id) 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) 
GROUP BY sales.stk_id;
```

I'm assuming "sales.stk_id=stk_type.id" is how they relate?

EDIT: forgot the where clause.